# How could I share a dedicated IP amongst multiple servers?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, virtualization, ip

I'm trying to split up a big server for a few people. They aren't going to run a website on it or anything like that but they want to at least connect to the server remotely.

My hosting provider is charging me about $3 a month for each dedicated IP and I think it's a bit ridiculous, especially for my use case. I was wondering if there was a way to connect to the same IP but give each virtual machine a different port?

```
Server 1: 50.50.50.50:5261 or bobserver.mydomain.com
Server 2: 50.50.50.50:5263 or mikeserver.mydomain.com
Server 3: 50.50.50.50:5266 or johnserver.mydomain.com
```

I know this is how Microsoft Azure kind of does their servers and I was wondering if there was anyway to replicate something like that. I've tried researching everywhere and I can't find anything.

Again, it doesn't matter how efficient or stable it would be.

Comment: Why does each user need a dedicated ip or a dedicated port, what are they doing ? Why can't you just tell them all to log into server.example.com? Alternatively why can't you just create multiple DNS A records or CNAME records that point to the relevant IP or A record ?

Comment: Create a fourth server and either use it as a load balancer or NAT.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic DNS is probably a better solution. You install a client (updater) on each server, it pings to your Dynamic DNS provider like dyn.com and that will keep your chosen domain name resolving to whatever dynamic IP address that server runs. You then SSH in on that FQDN/host instead of the IP address. Note there may be lag time at times when the IP address changes, but it doesn't sound like you need a high availability solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you are able to set some NAT rules, you can map the desired ports to each VM. In example for RDP

```
Source        Destination   Source Port   Destination Port
50.50.50.50   192.168.1.10  5261          3389
50.50.50.50   192.168.1.11  5262          3389
```

This should in my opinion work.

Cheers,

Maes